# Auth (digest) request from Servlet

Tags: java, authentication, tomcat, servlets, digest

I'm creating a small servlet. It's hosted at root, "/", and whatever comes after "/" is a resource, like "/myanim.swf". Most of the files are public, but some are private. For public files, they are just served, but for private files, I wish the browser to present an authentication box and have a Digest authentication sent back to the servlet, that can then verify it and serve the content. How should I implement the

```
if(!file.isPublic())
```

part? Since I want the browser to do the authentication, I don't want to use j_security_check mechanism

Cheers

Nik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Servlet spec supports this out of the box. "`j_security_check` mechanism" as you refer to it is only used during form-based authentication method whereas you will be using digest.

Here's a corresponding chapter from [J2EE tutorial](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bncas.html) and here's [an example](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bncbx.html#bncck) of how to configure basic authentication for a servlet (replacing it with a digest-based method is straightforward).